# Rendering to TBO

Tags: opengl

I need to render to [Buffer texture](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture).  Why TBO?  TBO can be mapped easily as CUDA resource for graphic interop.  It can also store byte sized data, which is what I need.  I was trying to find related  info in GL specs.  [Here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) it is stated that:

> Buffer Textures work like 1D texture, only they have a single image,
>   identified by mipmap level​ 0.

But when I try to attach TBO to FBO I am always getting "Missing attachment" error when checking completeness, which leads me to a conclusion that [GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexBuffer.xhtml) is not supported as FBO attachment.

Two questions:

1. Is it true?
2. Is the only alternative here to write to [SSBO](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object)

More detailed info:

I am getting

> GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT

When I am trying to attach the TBO to the framebuffer.There is no point to attach the whole code here as it is both heavily abstracted API and belive me,I am pretty experienced in using OpenGL and framebuffers.Attaching a regular GL_TEXTURE_2D works great.
Here is the chunk of the TBO creation and the attachment stage:

```
GLuint tbo;
GLuint tboTex;
glGenBuffers(1, &tbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, tbo);
glBufferData(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, viewportWidth * viewportHeight * 4, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, 0);
glGenTextures(1, &tboTex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, tboTex);
glTexBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL_RGBA8, tbo);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, 0);
```

Then attach to FBO:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, tboTex, 0);

///also tried:
/// glFramebufferTexture1D
/// glFramebufferTexture2D
```

Comment: Did you get any OpenGL errors? Can we see your code?

Comment: @NicolBolas see my update.

Comment: And what about OpenGL errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Buffer textures cannot be attached to FBOs](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glFramebufferTexture.xhtml):

> `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is generated by[sic] if `texture` is a buffer texture.

A good reminder for why you should always check your OpenGL errors.

> Is the only alternative here to write to SSBO

If your goal is to use a rendering operation to write stuff to a buffer object, you could also use [Image Load/Store operations](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store) with buffer textures. But if your hardware could handle that, then it should handle SSBOs too.

You could also try to use [geometry shaders](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader) and [transform feedback operations](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transform_Feedback) to write whatever you're trying to write.

However:

> It can also store byte sized data

Images can store "byte sized data" as well. The image format `GL_R8UI` represents a single-channel, 8-bit unsigned integer.

That doesn't resolve any CUDA-interop issues, but rendering to bytes is very possible.

Comment: But GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER is not listed as possible target in the specs.So I don't get you.I always check for GL errors.It doesn't help me to understand if TBO attachment is possible or not right now.I can't use GL images as I use one of CUDA based API which supports only buffers for mapping.

Comment: @MichaelIV: Post clarified. "*I always check for GL errors.*" And yet, the behavior you're getting suggests that you did not. The error should cause `glFrambufferTexture` to do nothing. Which is why the texture's completeness status is "missing attachment" rather than "incomplete attachment". So either you're not checking for errors or your implementation didn't issue the error correctly when you used a buffer texture.

Comment: Well,that's the first and only error the driver spits out in my case.NVidia GPUs.Anyway,well,it is enough for me to know TBO cannot be attached.Thanks for the info.